# what happen with pod install in react native?

Tags: react-native

I try to run: **npx pod-install**
after that it show me the message below :

*Pod installation complete! There are 84 dependencies from the Podfile and 95 total pods installed.
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.*

I don't know what problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got a successful installation.

Is the app working? Is there any other log besides that one? Don't get too frightened by warnings when installing packages, you'll get them most of the time.